# PHP string convert encoding from utf8 to cp1251 with replace impossible characters via html-mnemonics

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

I convert string encoding from wide `utf8` to limited encoding `cp1251`. I need to preserve some characters not included into cp1251.

In python 2.x there is a special function, which during encoding conversion replaces impossible characters with html-entities:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s_in = "Ø 125 mm".decode('utf8')
s_out = s_in.encode('cp1251', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
print s_out # prints &#216; 125 mm
```

[Live example on ideone](http://ideone.com/RPXeEB)

Is there any ready-to-use func/lib in PHP to do the task?

My code is:

```
<?php
$in = 'Ø 125 mm';
$out = mb_convert_encoding($in, 'cp1251', 'utf8');
echo $out; // prints ? 125 mm
```

[Live example on sandbox.onlinephpfunctions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef84c790a08c2de3c4ef87ef18a1a8d75c960791)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: try json_encode - see here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef84c790a08c2de3c4ef87ef18a1a8d75c960791

Comment: @ASR, json_encode outputs \u00d8 125 mm

Comment: @Kazz, htmlentities, as I understand, replaces everything it can into html-entities, not only characters, not presented in target encoding.
It produces ok results in my example, but it converts valid cp1251 symbols into html-entities http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a1c3f8c6c91029854c604ecffec5989315f50f1

Thought, it satisfy my current needs, It doesn't look like fully working solution.

Comment: Encodings and validation are both big pains :)

Comment: then is this better ? `strtr('<p>Ø 125 mm</p>', array_diff(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES), get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS)));`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php

Comment: Did you try with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` -
 here is the working sample http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfd9f38ed7ad8b668285be31004bfe2578da6436

Comment: @ASR, output contains utf8 characters not represented in cp1251

Comment: @Kazz, your `strtr` code looks well at first glance, it gives me ok results working with my data. You may post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

By using `iconv()` function in `PHP` you can convert string from one to another encoded scheme. Example:

```
$out = iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251//IGNORE", $in);
```

> If you append the string `//IGNORE`, characters that cannot be
>   represented in the target charset are silently discarded

For complete description see link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Seems like it doesn't convert encoding, output contains utf8 symbols

Comment: Strange but it returns something falsy, so I have empty strings in database when there is some impossible characters. `//TRANSLIT` directive gives `? 125 mm` result. Nevertheless, thanks for try

Answer (score 0):

Try `json_encode` with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

```
$in = 'Ø 125 mm';
$out = json_encode($in, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo json_decode($out, true);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfd9f38ed7ad8b668285be31004bfe2578da6436

Comment: output contains utf8 characters not represented in cp1251